# Why spark doesn't pick certificate?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a Java component for spark and it consumes **soap** service by building **SSL with JKS certificate**. I tested the component in local and I get the response from the soap service.

```
    service = new Token_Service();
    port = service.getPort(TokenLookupService.class);
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
              BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
              jsonSpec.getEndpoint());
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/path/to/my.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","mypswd");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","JKS");
   // call the service
   List<PANType> panFromToken = port.getPANFromToken(tokens);
```

This works fine when I debug/step through the code. But when I run `spark-submit` command, the certificate is not picked up and I get `403: Forbidden` error. I changed the the code to build SSL context manually (given below). It worked fine locally/debug-mode but during run-time I got `null` response (no 403).

```
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        String certPath = "/path/to/my.jks";
        String certPass = "myPassword";         
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());          
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(certPath), certPass.toCharArray());
        kmf.init(ks, certPass.toCharArray());
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", sc.getSocketFactory());
```

I tried running spark with -- conf option but got invalid argument error.

`--conf "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/my.jks" --conf "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=myPass"`

Comment: If you submit the spark jar to the cluster, are you sure that your certificate is bundled in the jar?

Comment: Make sure the jks certificate is in the hdfs when you provide that path.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that System.setProperty() was not working under spark-context. I was testing locally and not on any cluster but spark executor should have picked up the system properties. Nevertheless, setting up the SSL Socket Factory worked.